# Is there any other solution for $S_2(x)=y^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Define $S_2(n)=1^2+2^2+...+n^2$

> Is there any other solution for $S_2(x)=y^2$ other than
>
> $1^2=1^2$ and $1^2+2^2+3^2+...+24^2=70^2$
>
> where $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ ?

I checked between $1\le x\le 1000,1\le y\le 1000$

```
for(u=1,1000,for(a=1,1000,if(sum(q=1,u,q^2)==a^2,print([u,a]))))
[1, 1]
[24, 70]
```

Comment: Your algorithm can be improved substantially using that $6\cdot S_2(n) = n\cdot (n+1)(2n+1)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Lucas' square pyramid problem :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannonball_problem

solved by Watson more than 100 years ago. There are no further solutions in positive integers.