# Observation on Erdős–Moser equation.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

*Define*: $ S(n,m)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}i^m$ where $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}_+$

*Define*: $F_m$ is function as, there exist smallest integer $k$ with respect to $m$ such that, $$k^m\le S(k-1,m)$$ so $F_m=k$.

*Example*: $F_2=5$.

Let $S(F_m-1,m)$ convert in base $F_m$ so we can represent as $$S(F_m-1,m)= (\alpha_m,\alpha_{m-1},...,\alpha_1,\alpha_0)_{F_m}$$

Where $\alpha_i$ are digits of $S(F_m-1,m)$ in base $F_m$.

*Example*: $m=2\rightarrow S(F_2-1,2)=S(4,2)=30=(1,1,0)_5$.

---

*Table*

$$\begin{split}
S(F_m-1,m) &= (\alpha_m,\alpha_{m-1},...,\alpha_1,\alpha_0)_k  \\
S(2,1) &= (1,0)_3 \\S(4,2)
&=(1,1,0)_5 \\S(5,3)
&=(1,0,1,3)_6 \\S(7,4)
&=(1,1,1,0,4)_8 \\S(8,5)
&=(1,0,3,6,6,0)_9 \\S(10,6)
&=(1,1,3,1,4,5,0)_{11}\\S(11,7)
&=(1,0,6,11,8,6,1,0)_{12}\\S(13,8)
&=(1,1,6,2,9,0,7,6,7)_{14}\\S(14,9)
&=(1,0,11,3,0,11,11,3,9,0)_{15}\\S(15,10)
&=(1,0,1,10,2,7,12,9,3,2,8)_{16}\\S(17,11)
&=(1,0,16,7,11,6,5,16,11,4,16,9)_{18}\\S(18,12)
&=(1,0,5,0,6,18,13,14,3,5,11,17,0)_{19}\\
\vdots &= \vdots
\end{split}$$

> **Claim**
>
> 1) For all $m$, $\alpha_m\in\{1\}$
>
> 2) For all $m$, $\alpha_{m-1}\in\{0,1\}$
>
> 3) For all $m>2$, $\alpha_{m-2}\notin\{0\}$
>
> 4) $F_{m+1}\ge F_m$

The [Erdős–Moser equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Moser_equation) is ${\displaystyle 1^{m}+2^{m}+\cdots +(n-1)^{m}=(n)^{m}}$
where $n$ and $m$ are positive integers. The only known solution is $1^1 + 2^1 = 3^1$.

Third claim is consequence to Erdős–Moser equation conjecture.

The first two claims are posted here in a different mathematical format with specificity [check here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3548551/647719)

*I was not worked hard on this observation. may be you can disprove by counter example.thank you.*

---

Edit 1: Answer for first claim [check here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/353225/149083)

Edit 2: [find $x,y$ s.t.$S(x,m)=y^m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3494000/647719) This post is consequence to Erdős–Moser equation.

Comment: 3) fails for $m=35,96,126$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე ooops... And what about 2)?

Comment: 2) holds up to $m=1500$

Comment: Seems that $F_m$ is $2+$ the nearest integer to $m\times1.4426950412298405...$

Comment: Both 1) and 2) (and trivially 4) follow from much stronger statement that seems to be true: $F_{m+1}=F_m+1$ or $F_{m+1}=F_m+2$ for all $m$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  How can it be generalized to better understand the structure? may be it's help https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3393089/647719

Comment: Generalized in what direction? As for previous, I now checked experimentally that $F_m$ is $2+$ the nearest integer to $m/\ln2$ up to $m=10000$

Comment: In fact I seem to have a proof of that. By [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula), $F_m$ is $2+$ the nearest integer to $m$ times the inverse of largest real root of$$1-\frac{3(m+1)}{2m}t+\sum_{j=2}^mB_j\binom{m+1}j\frac{t^j}{m^j},$$where $B_j$ are the Bernoulli numbers. Since limit of $\binom{m+1}j/m^j$ is $1/(j!)$, for large $m$ we get close to the inverse of the root of$$1-\frac32t+\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{B_j}{j!}t^j,$$i. e. of the root of$$-t+\frac t{e^t-1},$$i. e. to the inverse of $\ln2$.

Comment: This then implies $F_{m+1}$ is either $F_m+1$ or $F_m+2$, since $1/\ln2$ is between 1 and 2

Comment: I am not making this an answer since (a) I am not entirely sure about all the details and more importantly (b) one must check in the literature, most likely this is known and can be simply referred to some paper

Comment: Yes, it seems that this is one of the easiest consequences of the results of the paper by [Gallot, Moree and Zudilin](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2011-80-274/S0025-5718-2010-02439-1/) mentioned in the Wikipedia article that the OP links to

Answer (score 3):

Later edit - everything below is a consequence of the fact that $F_m$ is $2+$ the nearest integer to $m/\ln2$, see comments to the OP. I am still leaving this - for amusement?

Instead of answer - just some curious facts about the numbers $F_m$. If one believes in 4), there is a quick Mathematica code to play with them:

```
iF[m_]:=iF[m]=If[m==0,2,Module[{k=iF[m-1]},While[HarmonicNumber[k-1,-m]<k^m,k++];k]]
```

They go like
$$
2,3,5,6,8,9,11,12,14,15,16,18,19,21,22,24,25,27,28,29,31,32,...
$$
The sequence ${F'}_m:=F_{m+1}-F_m$ goes like
$$
1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,...
$$
Let $\{{}^2F_1,{}^2F_2,{}^2F_3,...\}$ be the sequence $\{m\mid{F'}_m={F'}_{m+1}\}$; it goes like
$$
9,18,27,34,43,52,61,70,79,88,95,104,113,122,131,140,149,158,165,174,183,...
$$
and the sequence of its differences ${}^2{F'}_m:={}^2F_{m+1}-{}^2F_m$ goes like
$$
9,9,7,9,9,9,9,9,9,7,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,7,9,9,9,9,9,9,7,9,9,9,9,9,9,7,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,7,...
$$
Let further $\{{}^3F_1,{}^3F_2,{}^3F_3,...\}$ be the sequence $\{m\mid{}^2{F'}_m=7\}$; it goes like
$$
3,10,18,25,32,40,47,54,61,69,76,83,90,98,...
$$
and ${}^3{F'}_m:={}^3F_{m+1}-{}^3F_m$ goes like
$$
7,8,7,7,8,7,7,7,8,7,7,7,8,7,7,8,7,7,7,8,7,7,8,7,7,7,8,7,7,8,...
$$
Next, let $\{{}^4F_1,{}^4F_2,{}^4F_3,...\}$ be $\{m\mid{}^3{F'}_m=8\}$; it is
$$
2,5,9,13,16,20,23,27,30,34,38,41,45,...
$$
and ${}^4{F'}_m:={}^4F_{m+1}-{}^4F_m$ is
$$
3,4,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,4,3,4,3,4,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,4,3,4,3,4,4,3,4,3,4,...
$$
Continuing in the same way, with $\{m\mid{}^4{F'}_m=3\}$ I get ${}^5{F'}_m$
$$
3,2,2,3,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,3,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,3,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,3,2,...
$$
then ${}^6{F'}_m$
$$
3,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,3,...
$$
then ${}^7{F'}_m$
$$
2,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,...
$$

I wonder if this goes forever...

Comment: @Pruthviraj I get $F_8=14$. By the way, in your table you have $S(13,8)=(1,1,6,2,9,0,7,6,7)_{14}$, while in fact $S(14,8)=(1,3,2,7,0,7,10,12,7)_{15}$

Comment: Ok thanks for observation +1

Comment: Maybe we can generalize $F_m$ as,

Define $f_{m,i}=k$, minimum $k$ s.t. $k^{m-i}\le S(k-1,m)$ where $0\le i < m$. I observe $f_{m+1,i}\ge f_{m,i}$. In given case $F_m=f_{m,0}$.

Comment: @Pruthviraj In that paper by Gallot, Moree and Zudilin there are some results about the equation $S(k-1,m)=tk^m$ (in Section 5.2)