# An Inequalities related to power sum

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $S_m(n)=1^m+2^m+\cdots+n^m$

Show that the following inequalities are true for all $m,k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$

[1] $k\cdot(2km+m)^{2m-1}\le S_{2m-1}(2km+m-1)$

[2] $k\cdot(2km+m+k+1)^{2m}\le S_{2m}(2km+m+k)$

Example: for $m=k=1$ ; gives [1] $ 3\le3$ and [2] $25\le 30$.

both claims are verified up to $m,k\le50$. source code Pari GP

```
for(k=1,50,for(m=1,50,if(k*(2*k*m+m)^(2*m-1)>sum(t=1,2*k*m+m-1,t^(2*m-1)),print([k,m]))))
```

Apologize for deleting all previous updates.

update #1: (more on claim)

(1) $k\cdot(2km+m)^{2m-1}\le S_{2m-1}(2km+m-1)\le (k+1)\cdot(2km+m)^{2m-1}$

(2) $k\cdot(2km+m+k+1)^{2m}\le S_{2m}(2km+m+k)\le (k+1)\cdot(2km+m+k+1)^{2m}$

Comment: did you check if there are similar questions ??

Comment: @Spectre This one is much closer, [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3546797/647719)

Comment: then I'd suggest withdrawing the question, if this one is very much similar to the one you have provided now.