# find the smallest $n>1$ such that : $n(n+1)(2n+1)=6m^{2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

Problem :

> find the smallest natural number $n>1$ such that :
>
> $$n(n+1)(2n+1)=6m^{2}~~,m\in\mathbb{N}$$

I don't know the method to find $n$ but I try many time

$$n=1,2,3,....,24$$

Then I find $n=24$

$$24.25.49=6.70^{2}$$

Another try :

$$n\equiv r\pmod{6}~~,r=1,..,5$$

$n=6k$ then $k(6k+1)(12k+1)=m^{2}$

So $k,6k+1,12k+1$ is perfect square in same time I find $k=4$ so $n=24$
Also for all $n=6k+r$ I can't find $n$ ?

So I'm going to see you solution
Thanks!

Comment: If you are asking for the complete solution, this isn't easy.  https://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/paper21.pdf

Comment: @saulspatz yes sir very difficult to me

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos How we can solve it with simple method ?

Comment: I am not aware of any such solution.

Comment: Well, you've found the smallest $n$ that works.  Proving that there is no other $n$ is another matter.  It has a long history, as described at the beginning of the paper I linked.  There is an elementary solution at https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00029890.1990.11995558?needAccess=true but it isn't free.  You should be able to find it in a math library, though.

Comment: This is Lucas' square pyramid problem :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannonball_problem

solved by Watson more than 100 years ago. There are no further solutions in positive integers. Check this post 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3491396/647719